# C#: Exception - Parameter is not valid - Form Dispose method

Tags: c#, exception

While disposing the `object` of a `form` from the other an `exception` is throwing like`Parameter is not valid`

**Code to access the second form**

```
        Assembly X = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\Test.dll");
        Form frminv = (Form)X.CreateInstance("Test.Form1");
        frminv.Dispose();
```

Here is the form disposal method( from Designer.cs)

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);// exception is thrown from here
    }
```

Here is the stack trace

```
     at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList()
 at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(Image image)
 at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo..ctor(Image image)
 at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler onFrameChangedHandler)
 at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate(Boolean animate)
 at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate()
 at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
 at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntDestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
 at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
 at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DestroyHandle()
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle()
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at ICFTWaveForm.WaveForm.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 at XXXX.frmMain.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in E:\XXXX\XXXX\frmMain.Designer.cs:line 20
 at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
 at XXXX.TestComponents.OpenComponentForTestting(stComponents TestComponent, stTestStepDetails Test, enExecutionModeTypes Mode, Boolean IsVisibleMode, Int32 nStepIndex, Int32 nTotalSteps) in E:\My Projects\XXXXXXXX\frmMDIContainer.cs:line 3145
```

what will be the problem.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you put the stack trace here?

Comment: could show us the code that you use to instantiate the object you're trying to dispose? I think you may be trying to dispose of a static object so I just want to make sure its not that

Comment: Can you try to create a small sample to reproduce this issue... doesn't seem like the kind of thing you can solve remotely. The code looks okay.. Do you have any custom controls on this form ?

Comment: ok, I have no idea, someone light up the Jon Skeet sky signal

Comment: The first code snippet cannot be accurate.  Avoid editing it down to what you think is the problem.

Comment: @Gishu : Yes i'm using some custom controls in my form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have to look at the code to be sure, but perhaps I can help you look in the right places...

The stack trace indicates that a redraw of an animation in a pictureBox is occurring during the Dispose sequence. So why is the picturebox trying to do this when it's supposed to be dead?

In these sort of cases you may need to do something like: Close() your window before disposing it, shut things down cleanly (e.g. disable animation in the picturebox before calling base.Dispose()), or there may be other resources that are created in your class and need to be disposed before you can safely call base.Dispose. Alternatively, you may have already Disposed of something that is still needed (e.g. the Image that the pictureBox is trying to access) - check what disposing "components" will actually dispose of.