# "Parameter is not valid" Exception from get_FrameDimensionsList() on form construction

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have an application with a Windows Form which sometimes throws a "Parameter is not valid" exception in the wild.  The exception is raised at construction time while traversing auto-generated code (generated by Visual Studio).

Here are some relevant code snips.

```
// MainForm.cs
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
  public MyForm(Action shutdown_request_callback = null)
  {
    Visible = false;
    ShowInTaskbar = false;
    Opacity = 0;

    InitializeComponent();
    ...
  }
}

// MainForm.designer.cs, this is auto-generated
partial class MainForm
{
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
    ...
    this.StatusPane = new StatusPaneUserControl();
    ...
  }
}

// StatusPaneUserControl.cs
public partial class StatusPaneUserControl : UserControl
{
  public StatusPaneUserControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

// StatusPaneUserConrol.designer.cs, auto generated code
partial class StatusPaneUserControl
{
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
    this.FolderImage = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    ...
    // 
    // FolderImage
    // 
    this.FolderImage.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("FolderImage.Image")));
    this.FolderImage.InitialImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("FolderImage.InitialImage")));
    this.FolderImage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161, 45);
    this.FolderImage.Name = "FolderImage";
    this.FolderImage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(251, 219);
    this.FolderImage.TabIndex = 8;
    this.FolderImage.TabStop = false;
    this.FolderImage.WaitOnLoad = true;
    ...
    this.Controls.Add(this.FolderImage);
  }
}
```

The "Parameter is not valid" exception is raised indirectly from `Controls.Add`.  The actual stack is below.

```
ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList()
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(Image image)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo..ctor(Image image)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler onFrameChangedHandler)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate(Boolean animate)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.AssignParent(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   at MyNamespace.StatusPaneUserControl.InitializeComponent()
   at MyNamespace.MainForm.InitializeComponent()
   at MyNamespace.MainForm..ctor(Action shutdown_request_callback)
```

The exception seems to come from `get_FrameDimensionsList()` which doesn't seem to take any parameters which is confusing since the exception seems to say that some param is bad.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622985/c-exception-parameter-is-not-valid-form-dispose-method#) but is related to dispose which doesn't look applicable here (but would make sense).

Comment: Is this a "First Chance Exception"? Does it crash or continue normally? Sometimes these are benign and can be ignored.

Comment: [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,9221e07f844584a8) is the code which is throwing the exception. Looks like it's passed through from GDI+.

Comment: My suspicion is that the image hasn't finished loading when the control is added to the list. It's setting `WaitOnLoad` to true, but it does that after setting the image, and the default is false. If you remove the images from the property at design-time, and add them after initialization in the ctor, the error may disappear.

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard, thats a better guess than any of mine.  I'll look into that.  The tricky bit is that we can't reproduce the issue so I'll have to see how to best track this in the wild.  I wonder what'd happen if I changed WaitOnLoad to false.  If the issue is that that the image isn't finished loading before it's needed then maybe setting to false will help because some code branch will avoid traversing the failing path (or will load it properly).

Comment: changing WaitOnLoad to false didn't seem to help things.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found any solution?